# Querying Foreign keys data in Django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am looking to query my database and retrieve all the REAL values of the fields.
Instead I am getting Foreign keys id values. 
Can anyone help ?

Here is my models.py:

```
class Respondant(models.Model):
Respond_Id    = models.IntegerField(null=True)
Gender        = models.TextField(null=True)
Age           = models.TextField(null=True)
Country       = models.ForeignKey(Country,  related_name="respondant_Country")
Theme         = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="respondant_Theme")
Question      = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="respondant_Question")
def __str__(self):
    return " Respondant:{} ".format(self.Respond_Id)
```

The RespondantSerializer:

```
class RespondantSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Respondant
    fields=('Respond_Id' ,'Gender' ,  'Age',  'Answer')
```

My query set in api.py:

```
class Theme1Api(ListAPIView):
queryset = Respondant.objects.filter(Theme=1)
serializer_class = RespondantSerializer
name = 'theme1'

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Country = self.kwargs['Country']
    Question = self.kwargs['Question']
    return Respondant.objects.filter(Theme=1).filter(Question=Question).filter(Country=Country)
```

Here is an output:

```
 [{"Respond_Id": 258, "Gender": "Female", "Age": "18-21", "Answer": 424},
  {"Respond_Id": 258, "Gender": "Female", "Age": "18-21", "Answer": 428}]
```

Comment: I suppose you wan the Country, Theme, and Question in your json response? What does `RespondantSerializer` look like?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I want Answer real value instead of the id. I have added RespondantSerializer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `ModelSerializer` you can use the `depth` option to get nested representations of the relationship.

```
class RespondantSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Respondant
        fields=('Respond_Id' ,'Gender' ,  'Age',  'Answer')
        depth = 1
```

More details here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

If you want more control over that you can create an `AnswerSerializer` and use that instead

```
class RespondantSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Answer = AnswerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Respondant
        fields=('Respond_Id' ,'Gender' ,  'Age',  'Answer')
```

Or if you just want a value from the `Answer` object you can use a `SerializerMethodField`, more info here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

```
class RespondantSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Answer = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Respondant
        fields=('Respond_Id' ,'Gender' ,  'Age',  'Answer')

    def get_Answer(self, obj):
        # get your value from obj.Answer
        return obj.Answer.<your_value>
```